# How to integrate Chatbase with SpringBoot, using rest

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, resttemplate, chatbase

I use a springboot server with rest template to start my chatbot and I want to integrate with the chatbase dashboard services

Answer (score 0):

We do not have a Springboot specific guide, though any framework should suffice as long as the JSON message body is properly formatted.  Please see our [Quickstart](https://chatbase.com/documentation/quickstart) and [Tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/chatbase/index.html#0) for specifications on how to format the JSON message body.

Please feel free to contact chatbase-support@google.com if you have specific questions during the process.